# Add new element to the tree by id

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a new element to the tree by id. I'm using recursion for this. My attempt

```js
const treeData = [{
  title: 'parent 1',
  key: '0-0',
  children: [{
    title: 'parent 1-0',
    key: '0-0-0',
    disabled: true,
    children: [{
        title: 'leafffff',
        key: '0-0-0-0',
      }
    ],
  }, ],
}, ];

const recursiveUpdate = (data, key) => {
  return data.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (el.key === key) {
      acc.push({
        ...el,
        children: [
          ...el.children || [],
          {
            title: '111111111111',
            key: 'new-key'
          },
        ],
      });
    } else if (el.children) {
      recursiveUpdate(el.children, key);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(recursiveUpdate(treeData, '0-0-0'));
```

This function only works at the nesting level. Help me with this problem

Comment: what would the "correct" result look like in this case?

Comment: You don’t do anything with the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Should `recursiveUpdate` create a new tree or modify existing one?

Comment: @Harrison
another children should be added to the element with key: '0-0-0'

Comment: @Konrad modify this

Comment: @qwerty added a modify code snippet to my answer, check it pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your non-matched elements too:

```js
const treeData = [{
    title: 'parent 1',
    key: '0-0',
    children: [{
        title: 'parent 1-0',
        key: '0-0-0',
        disabled: true,
        children: [{
            title: 'leafffff',
            key: '0-0-0-0',
        }
        ],
    },],
},];

const recursiveUpdate = (data, key) => {
    return data.reduce((acc, el) => {
        if (el.key === key) {
            acc.push({
                ...el,
                children: [
                    ...el.children || [],
                    {
                        title: '111111111111',
                        key: 'new-key'
                    },
                ],
            });
        } else {
            acc.push({
                ...el,
                ...el.children ? { children: recursiveUpdate(el.children, key) } : {}
            });
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
}

console.log(recursiveUpdate(treeData, '0-0-0'));
```

Btw you don't need `Array:reduce()` here. The `Array:map()` is enough and it's faster:

```js
const treeData = [{
    title: 'parent 1',
    key: '0-0',
    children: [{
        title: 'parent 1-0',
        key: '0-0-0',
        disabled: true,
        children: [{
            title: 'leafffff',
            key: '0-0-0-0'
        }],
    },],
},];

const recursiveUpdate = (data, key) => data.map(el => ({
    ...el,
    ...el.key === key ? {
        children: [...el.children || [],
        {
            title: '111111111111',
            key: 'new-key'
        },
        ]
    } : el.children ? { children: recursiveUpdate(el.children, key) } : {},
}));

console.log(recursiveUpdate(treeData, '0-0-0'));
```

But the problem is the OP commented that he/she wants to MODIFY the existing data though his code definitely creates a copy. So for modifying the existing data, we could just find a needed node to modify and add an extra child:

```js
const treeData = [{
    title: 'parent 1',
    key: '0-0',
    children: [{
        title: 'parent 1-0',
        key: '0-0-0',
        disabled: true,
        children: [{
            title: 'leafffff',
            key: '0-0-0-0',
        }
        ],
    },],
},];

const findNode = (node, key) => {
    if (Array.isArray(node)) {
      node = {children: node};
    }else if (node.key === key) {
        return node;
    }
    for (const child of node.children || []) {
        const found = findNode(child, key);
        if (found) return found;
    }
};

const node = findNode(treeData, '0-0-0');
(node.children ??= []).push({
    title: '111111111111',
    key: 'new-key'
});

console.log(treeData);
```

And a benchmark of map vs reduce:

[image]

```html
<body></body>
<script benchmark data-count="1000000">

    const treeData = [{
        title: 'parent 1',
        key: '0-0',
        children: [{
            title: 'parent 1-0',
            key: '0-0-0',
            disabled: true,
            children: [{
                title: 'leafffff',
                key: '0-0-0-0',
                children: [{
                    title: 'some leaf',
                    key: '0-0-0-0-0'
                }]
            }],
        },],
    },];

    // @benchmark reduce
    const recursiveUpdate = (data, key) => {
        return data.reduce((acc, el) => {
            if (el.key === key) {
                acc.push({
                    ...el,
                    children: [
                        ...el.children || [],
                        {
                            title: '111111111111',
                            key: 'new-key'
                        },
                    ],
                });
            } else {
                acc.push({
                    ...el,
                    ...el.children ? { children: recursiveUpdate(el.children, key) } : {}
                });
            }
            return acc;
        }, []);
    }

    // @run
    recursiveUpdate(treeData, '0-0-0');

    // @benchmark Alexander's map
    const recursiveUpdate2 = (data, key) => data.map(el => ({
        ...el,
        ...el.key === key ? {
            children: [...el.children || [],
            {
                title: '111111111111',
                key: 'new-key'
            },
            ]
        } : el.children ? { children: recursiveUpdate(el.children, key) } : {},
    }));
    
    // @run
    recursiveUpdate2(treeData, '0-0-0');

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Can you test using this code

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Define the tree data -->
    <script>
      const treeData = [
        {
          title: "parent 1",
          key: "0-0",
          children: [
            {
              title: "parent 1-0",
              key: "0-0-0",
              disabled: true,
              children: [
                {
                  title: "leafffff",
                  key: "0-0-0-0",
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ];
    </script>

    <!-- Call the function -->
    <script>
      const recursiveUpdate = (data, key) => {
        return data.reduce((acc, el) => {
          if (el.key === key) {
            acc.push({
              ...el,
              children: [
                ...(el.children || []),
                {
                  title: "111111111111",
                  key: "new-key",
                },
              ],
            });
          } else if (el.children) {
            const updatedChildren = recursiveUpdate(el.children, key);
            if (updatedChildren.length > 0) {
              acc.push({
                ...el,
                children: updatedChildren,
              });
            }
          }
          return acc;
        }, []);
      };

      // Call the function with treeData and the target key
      const updatedTreeData = recursiveUpdate(treeData, "0-0-0");
      console.log(updatedTreeData);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit this - perhaps just reduce to the function parts? as it stands this produces `"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'",` when ran.  And WHY would you promote use of/use TWO `<script>` blocks instead of just one?  After you fix your syntax issue perhaps enhance to explain what is happening to your "been coding 1 day" self here.